# relative imports in python in flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have read numerous SO questions and blogs. I am trying to structure my flask application. The current structure of my application is the following:

```
application
    run_server.py
    /config
       __init__.py
       production.py
       staging.py
       development.py
    /app
       __init__.py
       /site
           __init__.py
           views.py
```

Now, inside `app/__init__.py` I want to access the config based on my environment( dev, staging, production).

```
from ..config import config
```

I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

I have tried using `-m` switch. 
I  have also tried to set `PYTHONPATH` as my root directory to tell interpreter what is  top level package.
I think I am missing some fundamental in relative imports.

Comment: You could import a module not a namespace, there is no config.py file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running your application through `run_server.py` then there is no need of relative import in `app/__init__.py`. You can simply say,

```
from config import <production/staging/development>
```

This is because, when your interpreter interprets `run_server.py`, at the line say, `from app import <something>`, it will fetch `app/__init__.py` content and try to execute them at toplevel i.e. from directory `application`.

Now, assume you are running `from ..config import config` at toplevel. Obviously, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [absolute import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). IMHO it makes things easier to grok

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from application.config import production
```

This is absolute because you are specifying the exact path you are importing from which reduces ambiguity.

Also, you are missing `__init__.py` in the `application` folder

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have `config`in `application/config/__init__.py`.

You also need `__init__.py` under `application` directory, if not, then the `application/app` is your top level package, you can not access `application/config`.